Prove the sequence $\lim_{ n \to \infty } a_{n}=1$ given $a_{n}=\frac{2n}{2n+\sin n}$ using definition of limit
I'm trying to prove that the sequence $a_{n}$ converges to 1 where $a_{n}$ is:
$$
a_{n}=\frac{2n}{2n+\sin n}
$$
Where:
$$
\lim_{ n \to \infty } a_{n}=1
$$
But I'm having trouble solving for $N$ and here's my current proof.
Let $\epsilon>0$ where $N=?$ for all $n>N$, we need to prove:
$$
|\frac{2n}{2n+\sin n}-1|<\epsilon
$$
$$
|\frac{2n}{2n+\sin n}-1\frac{2n+\sin n}{2n + \sin n}|=|\frac{-\sin n}{2n+\sin n}|=\frac{\sin n}{2n+\sin n}<\epsilon
$$
We know since $n>N$ meaning that:
$$
\frac{\sin n}{2n+\sin n}<\frac{\sin N}{2N+\sin N}=\epsilon
$$
Make $N$ the subject:
$$
\sin N =\epsilon(2N+\sin N)
$$
And that's pretty much where I got stuck since I'm not sure how to simplify this to make $N$ the subject.

Note $\sin n$ can actually be negative for arbitrarily large integers $n$, and also that $\lvert\sin n\rvert\le 1$.

How does $n>N$ give you $
\frac{\sin n}{2n+\sin n}<\frac{\sin N}{2N+\sin N}$?

$| { \sin n \over 2n + \sin n }| \le {1 \over 2n + \sin n} \le {1 \over 2n-1} \le {1 \over n}$.

Forgot you could simplify it like that.... thanks!

Quick question... how come it's $2n - 1$??? Does $2n + 1$ also work?

@CFD For $n\ge 1$, which value is larger, $\frac{1}{2n-1}$ or $\frac{1}{2n+1}$?

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N> \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{1}{\epsilon} +1 \right)$. You have for every $n \geqslant N$ :
$$ \left| \frac{2n}{2n+\sin n} -1 \right| < \epsilon$$

Thanks to the comments I've figured out a solution:
Proof:
Let $\epsilon>0$ and $N=\frac{1}{2\epsilon}+\frac{1}{2}$ then for all integers $n>N$,
$$
\left\lvert\frac{2n}{2n+\sin n}-1\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{-\sin n}{2n+\sin n}\right\rvert< \frac{1}{2n-1}< \frac{1}{2N-1}=\frac{1}{2\left( \frac{1}{2e}+\frac{1}{2} \right)-1}=\epsilon
$$
Thus proving that $a_{n}$ converges using the definition of limit.

Haha, I should check my work more carefully, appreciate the corrections!
